# Остановить сервис через некоторое время после его старта

Tags: java, android, service, сервисы

Как остановить сервис через некоторое время после его старта. Допустим, служба проработала минуту, теперь надо её убить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так: то, что вы напишите в "run" исполнится через количество миллисекунд, заданных числом в конце метода.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // Сделать что-то чрез 60с = 60 000мс
                //Тут останавливать сервис
                context.stopService(new Intent(context, Service.class));
            }
        }, 60000);
```

Соответственно поместите этот кусок кода в метод, коий запускается при старте сервиса.

Comment: Остановка - context.stopService(new Intent(context, Service.class));

Comment: @Rammsteinik
Обновил ответ.

Comment: Но postDelayed не гарантирует выполнение через длительный промежуток времени. Лучше использовать AlarmManager. Или же останавливать через postDelayed самому себя(т.е. писать это внутри сервиса)

Comment: А если основной поток будет занят чем-то тяжелым? конечно такого быть недолжно но всё таки? вообще я склоняюсь что у топик стартера уродливая конструкция программы.

Comment: @argamidon

А если сей код поместить в AsynkTask, коий будет запускаться при старте сервиса?